# Need Formula of transaction

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Cell A7 will need to charge $250, after Cell C3 hit $16,000. So any deals before the Cell C3 reaches $16,000 the Cell A7 will not charge the $250.

Comment: https://exceljet.net/formula/if-cell-is-this-or-that

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(A7>=16000,250,"")
```

[image]